# Duplicando a escrita no arquivo com php

Tags: php

Estou implementando uma classe FileImpl que contém um método write. Porém, no momento que vou escrever, parece que o request é duplicado. Ou seja, se eu tentar adicionar 1 data, como no exemplo abaixo...

```php
$file = new FileImpl('log.txt');
$file->write(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
```

Eu tenho esse resultado na minha saída da escrita do arquivo:

Exemplo de saída:

```
16/04/2019 04:47:58
16/04/2019 04:47:58
16/04/2019 04:54:55
16/04/2019 04:54:55
```

Realmente, não sei onde o erro se encontra. Veja a implementação da minha classe:

```php
class FileImpl {

  private $diretory;
  private $fileName;

  public function __construct(string $fileName, string $directory = NULL) {
    $this->fileName = $fileName;
    if ($directory != NULL)
      $this->diretory = $directory . date('dMY');
  }

  public function write($data) : void {
    if (!$this->diretory) {
      $file = fopen($this->fileName, 'a+');
      echo "Arquivo criado sem diretorio\n";
    } else {
        if (!is_dir($this->diretory)) {
          mkdir($this->diretory);
        }
        $file = fopen($this->diretory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->fileName, 'a+');
        echo "Arquivo criado com diretorio\n";
    }
    fwrite($file, $data."\r\n");
    fclose($file);
  }

}
```

Comment: Seu código funcionou perfeitamente no meu ambiente de teste. Ele tá sendo executado junto a outros scripts ou tá rodando só isso mesmo?

Comment: Rodando somente isso... Estranho...!

Comment: Da forma que está é impossível reproduzimos o problema e a única coisa que nos resta é inferir que o problema está em outra parte do código. A questão é se você apenas declarar a classe e executar apenas as duas linhas de código que colocou na pergunta ainda duplicará? Em outras palavras, será necessário elaborar um [mcve].

Comment: Essa é toda a minha classe de exemplo, neste exemplo, não tenho nada mais que isso em minha classe... sempre quando atualizo, para cunho de teste, a linha duplica...